# sum based joining table on comma seperated values

Tags: mysql, sql

I have table cost like this

[image]

and table benang

[image]

can I sum (benang.biaya) when id_benang in table cost have same values on table benang

so the result like this

id_benang    biaya

8        = 4000000

### 6        = 4000000

```
       8000000
```

sory for my bad english

Comment: `SELECT sum (benang.biaya) FROM cost JOIN benang ON FIND_IN_SET(benang.id_benang,cost.id_benang) WHERE benang.id_benang=8`

Comment: Fix you data structure to use a proper junction table.  Storing numbers as strings and not declaring foreign key relationships is just not the right way to use a relational database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presuming you want the total value from the benang table next to the cost information...

```
SELECT kain, id_cuci, cost_id_benang, SUM(biaya)
FROM
(
    SELECT b.id_benang, biaya, c.kain, c.id_cuci, c.id_benang as cost_id_benang
    FROM BENANG b
    INNER JOIN 
    COST c
    ON LOCATE( RTRIM(CAST(b.id_benang AS CHAR(10))),c.id_benang) > 0
)AS seperatedData
GROUP BY kain, id_cuci, cost_id_benang
```

Using this sample schema and seed data:

```
CREATE TABLE COST (kain int, id_benang varchar(10), id_cuci int);
CREATE TABLE BENANG (id_benang int, biaya int);

INSERT INTO COST (kain, id_benang, id_cuci)
VALUES(8,'8,6', 3);

INSERT INTO BENANG(id_benang, biaya)
SELECT 5,3000000 UNION ALL
SELECT 6,4000000 UNION ALL
SELECT 7,3000000 UNION ALL
SELECT 8,4000000;
```

Comment: can you explain what it's query  'ON LOCATE( RTRIM(CAST(b.id_benang AS CHAR(10))),c.id_benang) > 0
)AS seperatedData'

Comment: @faza LOCATE will return the position (as an integer) of where a given 'search string' is located in a given 'string to be searched'.  So for example, LOCATE('C','ABC') will return the integer value 3 because 'C' is found at position 3 in the string 'ABC'.

Therefore with the query above, we are basically saying "join the two tables wherever the value of BENANG.id_benang (e.g. 6) is found in the column COST.id_benang(e.g. '8,6')".  So in your example we will get two joins (one where 6 joins to '8,6' and one where 8 joins to '8,6').  We can then sum these.

Comment: @faza One thing to note - although the above works with your sample data you may come across issues with other data.  For example, if your BENANG.id_benang is 8, and you have COST.id_benang = '6,58' you wouldn't want to join those rows.  However, LOCATE('8','6,58') would return 4 since '8' is found at position 4 in '6,58' and therefore your rows would be joined.  One way around this is to wrap both with ',' so instead you would have LOCATE(',8,', ',6,58,') - note the extra commas!  This would return 0 since ',8,' is not found.  It's not very nice, but needs must when we can't change schema..